# PHP accept any number

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code inside my posts:

```
[quick_view product_id="10289" type="button" label="Quick View"]
```

and I want to have inside a function the number "10289" matching any number:

```
if (stripos($post-> post_content, '[quick_view product_id="XXXX" type="button" label="Quick View"]') !== false)
```

How can replace the "XXXX" to accept all numbers?

**Full snippet:**

```
function conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles($posts){
if (empty($posts)) return $posts;
$shortcode_found = false; // use this flag to see if styles and scripts   need to be enqueued
foreach ($posts as $post) {
if (stripos($post-> post_content, '[quick_view product_id="XXXX" type="button" label="Quick View"]') !== false) {
$shortcode_found = true; // bingo!
break;
}
}
if ($shortcode_found) {
// enqueue here
wp_enqueue_style('my-style', '/woocommerce.css');
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', '/script.js');
}
return $posts;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, Hope it will work fine.

**Regex:** `/product_id\s*\=\s*\"\d+\"/` This regular expression will look for digits in between `product_id="`<->`"`

**Examples:**

`product_id="xxAbcxx"` will be rejected.

`product_id="1212121"` will be accepted.

```
if(preg_match("/product_id\s*\=\s*\"\d+\"/", $post->post_content))
{
    echo "Accepted";   
}
```

***Your complete code will look like this.***

```
function conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles($posts)
{
    if (empty($posts))
        return $posts;
    $shortcode_found = false; // use this flag to see if styles and scripts   need to be enqueued
    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        if(preg_match("/product_id\s*\=\s*\"\d+\"/", $post->post_content))
        {
            $shortcode_found = true;   
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($shortcode_found)
    {
// enqueue here
        wp_enqueue_style('my-style', '/woocommerce.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('my-script', '/script.js');
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: This would not work if you wanted to also accept Hexdecimal numbers (though I doubt it's a real use case here).

Comment: @apokryfos You are right but here OP is not expecting decimal nos. OP is referring to product_id which might not come in decimal no. If its about product price i would have considered a case of decimal no. as well. Am i right?

Comment: Thanks, but as I am novice in php how do I will include it in my code?

Comment: @geoplous Can you share your complete code in your post?

Comment: @geoplous Updated my post with complete code you can check.

Comment: It is not working.
My initial code looks for the code:
    [quick_view product_id="10289" type="button" label="Quick View"]

I just want to replace the number with any number, in php terms...

Comment: Can you tell me the error you are getting? and Copy paste my code again and check whether it is working fine or not?

Comment: It does not produce error. It is not show the stylesheet I want

Comment: just add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very top of your code.

Comment: @geoplous Can you share `print_r($posts);` which is coming as an argument in your function.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Find the code here https://eval.in/777414 and If you run that page something will print and you have to tell me what you got.

Comment: I did that but nothing was printed

Comment: My complete code is the code you gave me to enter. I just paste it to my functions.php

Comment: Try to call this function `conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles` and share the output `conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles` ? I wont be able to help you out untill unless i see whats wrong? If possible after trying this just share the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Sahil's answer includes unnecessary bits of code and a suboptimal regex pattern. 
 For best performance, this is what readers should use:

```
function conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles($posts){
    foreach($posts as $post){
        if(preg_match('/product_id="\d/',$post->post_content)){
            wp_enqueue_style('my-style','/woocommerce.css');
            wp_enqueue_script('my-script','/script.js');
            break;
        }
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

What is the difference between my answer and Sahil's?

- The `empty()` condition before the `foreach()` loop is unnecessary as foreach will not iterate even once if the array is empty.
- Every declaration/use of `$shortcode_found` is unnecessary.
- Sahil's regex pattern allows matches for a range of white-space characters (not only a space, but tabs, newline, etc.) where the OP's sample input has none.
- His pattern escapes the `=` which is unnecessary and teaches an unnecessary habit.
- Checking for more than one digit as the value for `product_id` is unnecessary because if there is so little as one digit, the condition should correctly return a `true` result.  Since the OP has indicated that product id's are fully numeric in format there is no need to check the entire value.  If there is concern for the full value then `/product_id="\d+"/` would do the trick.